# Unity connecting to Dall-E API when using image param?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, openai-api, text2image

How would one use the Dall-E text-to-image API's `image` and `mask` parameters in Unity C#?

For background, something like the following works for the other parameters like `prompt` (full code on [GitHub](https://github.com/JPhilipp/AIConnectors)):

```
string apiMode = "generations";
string apiUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/" + apiMode;

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(apiUrl, "");
www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + key);

string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aiParams, Formatting.None, serializerSettings);

www.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

When using `apiMode` "edits" or "variations" though, as per [Dall-E's documentation](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/images), it will return an API error suggesting to switch to content-type "multipart/form-data". How would one use this and add the binary data for `image` or `mask`, given some `byte[]` for the png? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) -> overload that takes [`List<IMultipartFormSection>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.IMultipartFormSection.html) will automatically use this content type header and there you can provide [`MultipartFormFileSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection.html) and [`MultipartFormDataSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormDataSection.html) sections.

The example is unfortunately useless but it would probably look somewhat like e.g.

```
 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aiParams, Formatting.None, serializerSettings);
 var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
 var formParts = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
 formParts.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("data", jsonBytes, "application/json"));
 formParts.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("image", yourFileContentBytes, "YourFileName.png", "image/png"));

 using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://www.my-server.com/myform", formParts))
 {
     www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + key);
     yield return www.SendWebRequest();

     if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
     {
         Debug.Log(www.error);
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Strange, Dall-E now replies with "'image' is a required property", even though I've used `formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("image", aiParams.image, "image.png", "image/png"));` and added that formData in the Post request, and the `byte[]` image is filled with content. (I've had the same Dall-E reply in the past when I simply didn't have any `image` param.)

Comment: Sorry, ignore the previous, I'm now further ahead after rewriting more parts to your pattern. I'm now at the Dall-E return message "Additional properties are not allowed ('data' was unexpected)", so I guess now I have to figure out under what name to pass the json (I picked "data"), and as last resort, pass the values one by one as formParts.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen usually afaik `data` and `files` would be the most common one .. I'm actually impressed that the Dall-E API is so verbose and tells you exactly what they expect :D Glad you could figure it out

Comment: I ended up only using JSON serialization when using their non-image API endpoints, and listing the few parameters one by one otherwise ([new GitHub code for reference](https://github.com/JPhilipp/AIConnectors/blob/main/ImageAI/DallE/ImageAIDallE.cs)). The code is less streamlined than I would like because it tries to have a somewhat unified approach when switching between Dall-E, StableDiffusion and Replicate.com-StableDiffusion, even though all 3 APIs are really doing it differently. In any case, all works now, thanks!

Comment: @PhilippLenssen I'm getting the "image is required property" response too in my POSTMAN and API call via Swift. Any leads on how you debugged that?

Comment: @AnupamChugh You can find my resulting and working Unity Dall-E API code [here on GitHub](https://github.com/JPhilipp/AIConnectors). Maybe that can help you. Note `image` should only be needed if you use the API modes `edits` or `variations`, but not when using `generations`, so try the latter if that's the one you want.